# set umask to 0002 for sftp and scp

Tags: debian, ssh

I want files sent to my server using sftp and scp to be group-writable.  How can I do that?

I tried using libpam-umask from http://wiki.debian.org/DebianDesktopHowTo but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**  Is there any way I can troubleshoot `pam`?  Is there a log?  Is there any common reason why `libpam-umask` would not work?  Do I have to install something?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar umask problems: trying to get all files in a directory to be group readable no matter who created them.

I got a bit stuck at first; I could set the sticky bit on the group, so all files had same group, but, at first, could find no way to set permissions consistently and correctly. (The use of a cron job to regularly put it right did not seem satisfactory.)

But then I found the solution.
Posix ACLs, you can set in a directory properties(users, groups, permissions/modes) to inherit, setting the default mode for user and group will have the effect that you want.

You will probably need to install it, and new backup tools (the default ones don't always know about ACLs)

as root once:

```
apt-get install acl
```

as owner of directory (the 3rd line sets the default mode to the current mode for all directories in $dir):

```
dir=directory_to_fix
chmod -R ug+rwX 
find $dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -i{}  bash -c "getfacl --access {} | setfacl -d -M- {}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think PAM reads the default umask from `/etc/login.defs` as of Debian 6.0, but I do not currently have access to a system to check on.

Comment: The comments in this file (on lenny) warn that the setting is only used by `login`, and that in general one should use the `pam_umask` module.

Comment: Right, on Squeeze I believe the comment says that pam_umask now reads the value from `login.defs`.

Comment: I edited `/etc/login.defs` and it didn't work

Comment: @JoelFan: default is `#UseLogin no` in Debian. So that's why it wouldn't work.